# Finding the Eigenspace and Basis of a Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I've been given the matrix: $$B = \begin{bmatrix}4& 2&-2\\3&-1&2\\2&2&0\end{bmatrix}$$
And found its Eigenvalues to be $\lambda=-3,2,4.$ I now need to calculate its eigenspace, but am unsure of wether I'm doing it correctly. I set up the matrix to be:
$$B-(-3) I=\begin{bmatrix}4-(-3)& 2&-2\\3&-1-(-3)&2\\2&2&0-(-3)\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}7& 2&-2\\3&2&2\\2&2&3\end{bmatrix}$$
I know that I need to set these equal to $B\vec{x}=\vec{0}$ to find the eigenspace. I start by reducing $B$, but keep getting the identity matrix implying $x_1,x_2,x_3=0.$ I don't think this is correct, but am also lost on what comes next. If it is correct, does that mean that my basis could be:
$$\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}\text{ or }\begin{bmatrix}2\\2\\2\end{bmatrix}\text{ etc...}$$

Sorry if this is a lot to ask or even a simple thing. I am struggling to wrap my head around this and could use any help!

Comment: You don't want to reduce $B$. You want to reduce $B-(-3I)=B+3I$. And when I start reducing the matrix you give for $B+3I$, I get a row of zeros, so it definitely has a nonzero solution. You would to show us what reduction you are doing to see where your error may lie.

Comment: Probably somenthing went wrong in the reduction. $(2,-5,2)$ is an eigenvector for $\lambda=-3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 7 & 2 & -2 \\ 3 & 2 & 2 \\ 2 & 2 & 3 \end{pmatrix}\to
 \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2/7 & -2/7 \\ 0 & 8/7 & 20/7 \\ 0 & 10/7 & 25/7 \end{pmatrix} \to
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2/7 & -2/7 \\ 0 & 1 & 5/2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \to
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 5/2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
Thus the kernel is given by $(x,y,z)$ with $z=x$ and $y=-5/2 z=-5/2x$, which gives you the basis $\{ (1,-5/2,1\}$ or $\{(2,-5,2)\}$, if you prefer this.

For the other eigenvalues proceed the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the matrix$$\begin{bmatrix}7&2&-2\\3&2&2\\2&2&3\end{bmatrix}.$$As a first step, you can divide the first line by $7$, getting:$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & \frac{2}{7} & -\frac{2}{7} \\ 3 & 2 & 2 \\ 2 & 2 & 3\end{bmatrix}.$$Then, you can add to second line the first line times $-3$ and add to the third line the second line times $-2$, getting$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & \frac{2}{7} & -\frac{2}{7} \\ 0 & \frac{8}{7} & \frac{20}{7} \\ 0 & \frac{10}{7} & \frac{25}{7}\end{bmatrix}.$$Now, you can divide the second line by $\frac87$, getting$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & \frac{2}{7} & -\frac{2}{7} \\ 0 & 1 & \frac{5}{2} \\ 0 & \frac{10}{7} & \frac{25}{7}\end{bmatrix}.$$Then, you add to the first line the second line times $-\frac27$ and you add to the third line the second line times $-\frac{10}7$. You will get$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & \frac{5}{2} \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}.$$And now your system has become$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}x-z=0\\y+\frac52z=0,\end{array}\right.$$a solution of which is $\left(1,-\frac52,1\right)$.